# How can we access a Facebook account if it was setup by a 3rd party?

Tags: facebook-pages, login, authentication

A client of ours had their Facebook business page set up by someone who has disappeared. The business page is here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/A-Step-Ahead-Child-Development-Center/211673368859321

How can our client get access to her business page to make changes?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the page, make sure your logged in, under the avatar, the links on the left hand side you will see the following options:

- **Is this your business?**
- Do you know the owner?
- Create a Page
- Add to My Page's Favorites
  etc...

Click "Is this your business?" and proceed with verification. If you fail at that, contact Facebook customer support and (it has worked in the past), if you can provide verification (they request) that you are infact the owner of the business they will manually transfer access over to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to run thru the process.